# Draw NSString in current context color

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsstring, drawing

I'm currently drawing an `NSString` into a `NSGraphicsContext` using:

```
    [attribute drawAtPoint:CGPointZero
               withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
```

The problem is that this always draws the text in black. I know there is a font color attribute, but inside the drawing function I don't have the color. All I know is that the current stroke and fill color of the context is set correctly. It seems there isn't a way to extract the current color from the context, so I can't use that.

There doesn't seem to be a draw function that just takes a font, like there is on iOS.

How can I draw the string in the current color of the context?